# Equivalent Systems of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So, a problem in linear algebra deals with solving a system of equations.
How do we prove that given that two systems of equations are equivalent, they have the same solutions?
Heuristically we could argue that if the two systems are equivalent, one system can be made the same as the other using row operations and so, would have same solutions. But, how do we mathematically prove this?

P.S.: Two systems are equivalent if all equations in system A is a linear combination of equation in system B.

Comment: The row operations correspond to pretty basic operations.  Swapping two rows is the same as writing the equations in a different order (which has no effect on the solutions); multiplying a row by a constant is an application of multiplicative cancelation; adding a (constant times a) row to another is an application of additive cancelation.

Comment: Ehr... what is your definition of "equivalent systems of equations"? Because mine is "two systems of linear equations are equivalent if and only if they have the same set of solutions." With that definition, you prove it by saying "By definition."

Comment: System $A$ implies system $B$ if every solution of $A$ is also a solution of $B$.

Comment: Two systems are equivalent if all equations in system A is a linear combination of equation in system B.

Comment: That's not a correct definition. The system $0x = 0$ and the system $x=1$ are two systems of linear equations, and every equation in the first system is a linear combination of the equations in the second system. But the systems are not equivalent under any sensible definition.

Comment: I might be wrong here but how can 0x = 0 and x = 1 be linear comb. of each other. Cause like to there is no way to reach x = 1 from 0x = 0.

Comment: I mean, if we add 1 to both LHS and RHS of system 1, we get 1= 1 and if we multiply by 1, we get 0. So, how can we reach x = 1 from 0x = 0?